# Delete rows from ArrayList#1 that appear in another ArrayList#2 and are non-unique in ArrayList#1

Tags: java, arraylist

There are two arraylists:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
ArrayList<Integer[]> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
arr1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
arr1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,2});
arr1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
arr1.add(new Integer[]{1,1,1});
arr1.add(new Integer[]{1,1,1});

arr2.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
arr2.add(new Integer[]{1,2,2});
```

How to delete rows from `arr1` that appear in `arr2` and that are non-unique in `arr1`? E.g. in this example I would need to delete only `{1,2,3}`, because it appears more than once in `arr1`. The only solution that comes to my mind is to use 4 FOR loops, but it seems to be very inefficient solution.

**Edit#1**
Resulting `arr1: {1,2,3},{1,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}`

Comment: In your example, what do you expect the resulting `arr1` to be?

Comment: Resulting arr1: {1,2,3},{1,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you can use a `List` instead of array then you could do something as follows:

```
List<List<Integer>> arr1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();        
List<List<Integer>> arr2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 2}));
arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 1, 1}));
arr1.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 1, 1}));

arr2.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
arr2.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 2}));

System.out.println(arr1);
System.out.println(arr2);

Set<List<Integer>> set1 = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();        
Iterator<List<Integer>> it = arr1.iterator(); 

while(it.hasNext()) {
    List<Integer> curr = it.next();
    if(!set1.add(curr) && arr2.contains(curr)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(arr1);
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: How can I use Iterator in case I have List<MyClass> instead of List<Integer>?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: Iterator<MyClass> it = myClassList.iterator();

Comment: I assume that if (!set1.add(curr) && selectedTokens.contains(curr)) does not work properly for List<MyClass>. MyClass has two fields: String key and Integer[] values. I checked your solution. It works fine for List<Integer>, but does not work for MyClass (?).

Comment: Make sure your class `MyClass` provides a proper implementations for the `equals` and the `hashCode` methods.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: If you are having trouble implementing those methods, post a new question.

Comment: I don't know how to implement hashCode for MyClass, because equals is applied to String key like: Row row = (Row)obj;
              return (key == row.key). @Override
        public int hashCode () {
            return this.key;
        }. Ok, I will post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Sort list 1.  Loop through list 1 starting at `[1]`.  If there is a duplicate `(a[i] == a[i-1])`, then look for that array in list 2.  If it's there, remove `a[i]`.

Note that in Java, you cannot modify a list as you loop through it so you'll actually need to keep a separate list of arrays that you want to delete from list 1 once you're done looping.

This will result in removing all of the duplicates from list 1.

Comment: Is it an efficient solution for two-dimensional arrays like arr1: {1,2,3},{1,2,2},{1,1,1}?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set`s, that would remove the non-uniques. You then can use `removeAll` and `retainAll`.
Use a wrapper class for the `Integer[]` (or `int[]`) which can use `Arrays.equals`.

```
public class IntArray implements Comparable<IntArray> {
    Integer[] items;

    public IntArray() {
        this.items = new Integer[0];
    }

    public IntArray(int... items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I use removeAll and retainAll in this particular case?

Comment: `arr1.removeAll(arr2)` would shrink arr1 by removing all that also are in arr2. I mentioned `retainAll` only for its obscure name and its equal usefulness for the complement: removing the elements that are _not_ in arr2.

Answer (score 1):

Using list will be something like this:

```
Loop through 2 
For every element A, loop through 1 and delete element B if it matches A.
```

If you simply leave the deleted element as null and only clean up the empty spot left by the deletion in the end rather than trying to shift the elements all the time, this will reduce the amount of shifting(an O(n) operation) and improve overall time from `O(n^2*m^2)` to `O(n*m)`.

If you can use `sorted List1`, you can look up and delete in O(logn), the total complexity will then be `mlogn`

If you can use `HashMap`, which will allow you to look up and delete in O(1), you can further decrease the time complexity to basically `O(m)`, then you can use one loop to go through list 2 and remove from set 1 all the same element.

```
Loop through List 1
     Add element to HashMap:Element -> Count (the count is here to preserve duplicates)
     If already exist in HashMap, Count++
Loop through List 2 
     For every element A, set B.get(A) = 0
Iterate through the HashMap
     For every entry, add the entry to the List *Count* times (rebuild list)
```

If you are doing this for real, there are helper methods each step of the way, use them.