# Code for deleting rows from ArrayList#1 that appear in another ArrayList#2 and are non-unique in ArrayList#1

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, hashcode

This post is the continuation of [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808604/delete-rows-from-arraylist1-that-appear-in-another-arraylist2-and-are-non-uniq). Now I have a code that I'd like to compile. The only difference is that now I'm using lists of my own class `List<Row>` instead of `List<Integer[]>`. In particular look at `hashCode` in Row, because it provides a compilation error.

```
    public class Row {
          private String key;
          private Integer[] values;

          public Row(String k,Integer[] v) {
              this.key = k;
              this.values = v;
          }

          public String getKey() {
              return this.key;
          }

          public Integer[] getValues() {
              return this.values;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean equals(Object obj) {
              if(this == obj)
                  return true;
              if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
                  return false;
              // object must be Row at this point
              Row row = (Row)obj;
                  return ((key == row.key) && (values == row.values));
          }

          @Override
          public int hashCode () { // HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM. DON'T KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT
              return this.key;
          }

    }

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Row> allRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        allRows.add(new Row("0",new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
        allRows.add(new Row("0",new Integer[]{1,2,2}));
        allRows.add(new Row("1",new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
        allRows.add(new Row("2",new Integer[]{1,1,1}));
        allRows.add(new Row("2",new Integer[]{1,1,1}));

List<Row> selectedRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
            selectedRows.add(new Row("0",new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
            selectedRows.add(new Row("2",new Integer[]{1,1,1}));

    System.out.println(allRows);
    System.out.println(selectedRows);
        List<Row> refreshedRows = refreshRows(allRows,selectedRows);
        System.out.println(refreshedRows);

    }

    private static List<Row> refreshRows(List<Row> allRows,List<Row> selectedRows) {
        Set<Row> set1 = new HashSet<Row>();
        Iterator<Row> it = allRows.iterator(); 

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Row curr = it.next();
            if (!set1.add(curr) && selectedRows.contains(curr)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        return allRows;
    }
}
```

The result, i.e. `refreshedArray`, should be equal to:

```
key = "0", values = {1,2,3}
key = "0", values = {1,2,2};
key = "1", values = {1,2,3};
key = "2", values = {1,1,1};
```

Comment: If the solution provided on your previous post has to work on the `Row`s then the equality of your `Row`s should only depend on the `values` field. I think you didn't exactly reflect your situation in that post. If you need to include `key` as a basis of equality of `Row`s, then I think you need a different approach to solve your issue.

Comment: yes, I need to take into account both key and values...

Comment: `key = "0", values = {1,2,3}`, `key = "1", values = {1,2,3}`. Suppose, you original list has those two `Row`s. Those are not really two duplicate `Row`s considering both `key` and `values`. But should the solution remove one of those based on the same `values` even if they `key`s are different?

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ: No, if the keys are different then the solution should not remove the entries even if the values are the same. The entries are considered as duplicate only if both the keys and values are the same.

Comment: In that case it should work, see the answer below for the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following. Despite minor changes, most of the code is generated by Netbeans IDE 7.0:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Row other = (Row) obj;
    if ((this.key == null) ? (other.key != null) : !this.key.equals(other.key)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(this.values, other.values)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 79 * hash + (this.key != null ? this.key.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 79 * hash + java.util.Arrays.deepHashCode(this.values);
    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature for `hashcode()`.  It returns a primitive integer.  You are returning `key` which is of type `String`.   Try something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 31 + key.hashCode();
    //hash = hash * 31 + otherFields.hashCode() etc
    return hash;
}
```

which your IDE can even generate for you.  You should probably read up on [hashcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29).  Your equals method looks wrong too.  What is meant by comparing the two Integer arrays for equality?

Comment: What's the point of all this math? Why not just return `key.hashCode()`?

Comment: But my class Row has two fields, such as String key and Integer[] values. Both of them are used in the function 'equal'. So, what will be the hashCode for this case?

Comment: @JB - yeah he could.  If he has other fields a formula like the one my IDE generated might be useful.